# Python recursive regex for checking matching parentheses?

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently working on a mathematical function parser in python where I'm using regex to match expected forms of functions, e.g. 'f(x,y) = (x^2, x+y)'

The current regex pattern for reckognizing such functions that I'm using is given by:

```py
import re
import regex

def match_function(in_str):
    #Checks whether or not an input string matches the regular expression
    #for a function, in terms of what makes a function usually valid in mathematics

    #Returns an iterable of re.Match objects

    pattern = "([a-zA-Z]|[0-9])+\s*\({1}([a-zA-Z](,)*)+(\){1})\s*=+\s*(\()+[^()]*\){1}"

    return regex.finditer(regex, in_str)
```

In this solution, the regex expects exactly one open parentheses and one closed parentheses. I would like to generalize that to accept any amount of (at least one) matching open and closed parentheses.

For example,
'f(x,y,z) = (x*(y+z), y, z)'.

Looking through online resources, it seems the python default library re for regex does not support recursion, so I installed the python regex external library (documentation at https://pypi.org/project/regex/) that extends the base functionality of the re library.

I attempted to use the recursion expression `(?R)` in a test function;

```
def match_closed_parentheses(in_str):
    pattern = "\((([^\(\)]*)|(?R))\)"
    return regex.match(pattern, in_str)
```

I intend this test function to match any strings of the form:
"( (()) () )" with nested parentheses.

If the parantheses are mismatched for example as in "( ( ))))  )" the regex should match "( ( )) ".

It also does not care as if there are extra open parantheses : " ( (((( )" should match as "( (((( )", since the code inside the 'main' parantheses will be parsed separately in a dynamic compiler.

But the output of  `matched_closed_parentheses`

```
print(match_closed_parentheses("()"))
print(match_closed_parentheses("(a,b,c)"))
print(match_closed_parentheses("(a+(b+c))"))
```

was not what I expected:

```
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 2), match='()'>
<regex.Match object; span=(0, 7), match='(a,b,c)'>
None
```

If someone could explain the output of `match_closed_parentheses`and point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

Edit: Clarified the external regex library I'm using and the intended behaviour of `match_closed_parentheses`

Edit: I appreciate the helpful answers, but I have already solved this problem. The issue I was having was not checking that the pattern inside the parantheses happened zero or more times(Kleene Star).
I Will mark my answer as solved in two days as soon as I can.

Comment: you import python regex module by import re not by import regex

Comment: could you show me example of in_str?

Comment: @Cyber-Tech regex is an external library that extends the functionality of the standard python re. I was using re in another part of the file, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Cyber-Tech I clarified the expected behaviour of match_closed_parentheses in the post and gave some examples explaining the behaviour. Other examples of in_str are found in the output section.

Comment: iam debuging it in my IDE. give me few minutes.

Comment: @Cyber-Tech I figured it out. I forgot to Kleene star the inner part of the expression. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I suggest you use a stack for this. If a character in the string is `'('` it is pushed onto the stack. If the character is '`)`' the top character on the stack must be `'('`, in which case it is popped from the stack. If the stack is empty or the character is not `'('`, parentheses are unbalanced and you are finished, Similarly `'['` (`'{'`) is pushed onto the stack and `']'` (`'}'`) requires the top character on the stack to be `'['` (`'{'`), which is popped from the stack. Lastly, after examining each character in the string the stack must be empty.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes! That is indeed the simplest algorithm for matching parentheses and would have been convenient. However, there was a need for regular expressions since in the flexible computational engine this is a part of, you can input multiple functions. This algorithm would return true for "f(x,y) = x+y, y+z", "f(x = y)", "f(x) = (x^2 f2) = (x,y,z)", all of which are supposed to be false. It would then be difficult to subsequently parse, error check and dynamically compile. The regex was needed for a reason.

Comment: I don't understand why any of those three examples should be false, assuming true means the parentheses are balanced (which is what use of a stack would return).

Comment: In the context I intend to use the strings, that were matched by the regex, these should not be matched where as your algorithm does. 

I wanted to avoid having an algorithm that checks a valid function name, then a valid set of variables, then a valid set of output functions, where each should be properly balanced. It seems reasonable to opt for the alternative of a regex which is more powerful and syntatically compact, that does all of the above things.

I have already solved the problem using a compact regex.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. Using the Kleene star operator on the inner group solves the issue:

```
pattern = "\((([^\(\)]*)|(?R))*\)"
```

It even rejects when there are too many open parantheses, which is desirable over leaving them there, so the dynamical compiler has less issues to troubleshoot.

Comment: Your regex matches three strings [here](https://regex101.com/r/YUdcz0/1/), two of which have unbalanced parentheses. Have I misunderstood what you are trying to do?

Comment: In these types of expressions, the extra parentheses either won't mather when they are parsed later on, or will raise an exception while trying to dynamically compile later on.The idea is that the strings are parsed in ways so that it is easy to provide an explanation to the user (on the webpage) with an output like 'invalid function declaration' or 'invalid variable definition' or 'invalid output function definition'. When matching the regex in this way, it is easy to do the above by splitting the resulting match at the 'equals sign' then the first open parantheses of each subexpression.

Comment: Your solutions are valid for the general problem, but my idea in this instance was a compact low-maintenance way of matching functions, followed by simple parsing and dynamic compiling. There is probably a better regex to do what I'm aiming for, but for nowthis solution works with the rest of the codebase. I'll probably delete this post, because the problem/solution is too specific. It's also not realistic to include the rest of the codebase in the post unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def match_function(in_str):

    pattern = "[\w(\w,\w)]* = [(\w^\w, \w+\w)]*"

    result = re.search(pattern, in_str)
    if result:
        return result
    else:
        return "No match"
print(match_function('hello? world f(x,y) = (x^2, x+y)'))
```

output

```
<re.Match object; span=(13, 32), match='f(x,y) = (x^2, x+y)'>
```

I did not exactly understand what you want to do but hopefully this example will helps. Otherwise, if you are using python3 then I insist on `import re` also your regex is not correct. If you are new to Python regex, I strongly suggest to do basic to intermediate Python regex course first. Else, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm trying to build a flexible computational engine for a variety of non-euclidean computation methods, that is more accessible than what is currently available.
I already have code that dynamically compiles input strings into python and numpy computable functions. This regex attemps to match what mathematicians would describe as a function, so it can be later parsed into a 'function name', 'variables' and a 'set of output functions'. The set of output functions will be dynamically compiled then evaluated based on other functions.
Hope that clears thigs up a little!

Comment: And unfortunately the python standard library re doesn't support recursion in regular expressions, unlike some other languages, so I am forced to use an external library. :(

Answer (score 0):

It will be hard regex patterns for you to figure out. Here another example to match 3 parenthesis left and right. What I understood is that your actual issue is to design an exact pattern to match your needs.

I made this parenthesis example for you which will match 1 parenthesis or more from left and right with one or more \w

```
 def match_function(in_str):

    pattern = "([(]*\w),(\w[)]*)"

    result = re.search(pattern, in_str)

    if result:
        return result
    else:
        return "No match"
print(match_function('hello? world f((((x,y))) = ((x^2, x+y))'))
```

output

```
<re.Match object; span=(14, 24), match='((((x,y)))'>
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of doing it like that, that's clever!

The issue is that it doesn't fit the larger codebase of my project. The input string in general could contain multiple functions and I think this regular expression may confuse multiple functions. Also keep in mind the set of output functions can be any number, not just two.

But this does mostly answer the title question, so I'll mark this as correct for now.

Comment: Regex its like a translation form source to target. In order to succeed a good translation we should master the source and the target languages first. It will be a considering regex pattern fight for you  :-) That's why I suggested to learn Python regex first. While it looks easy to understand but without a great tutor you will miss most of useful how-to.

Comment: All right. As a plan for your project, I think it will be better to append each matched pattern in .txt file in a list. Then you can comfortably do whatever you want with later. Its a common approach. This is a advanced hard assessment I passed which could give you few useful hints. (Python Regex)[https://github.com/IT-Support-L2/generating_html_reports/blob/master/csv_report_generate.py] I also think cutting the entire project into small pieces would help a lot. Good Luck.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my background. I have experience with regex from a theoretical standpoint (as in theorems, lemmas, proofs), symbolic computation as well as software engineering and a great deal of experience in abstract mathematics.
I don't have much experience implementing regex in python whereas I do in other languages. In the other languages I've used they have built in recursion.I do appreciate the help though and I will keep in mind your suggestions. 

The larger codebase is a webapp, so .txt files are a poor substitute for a database if the need arises.

Comment: Your regex matches, for example, `'hello? world f x,y])} = ({[x^2, x+y'.match?'`.